# The hypothesis of the unbounded product of the digits of a prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

> Hypothesis: the product of the digits of prime numbers is not bounded from above

This task arose from one research task, so maybe it is very complex and I do not know how to approach it. I will be happy with any help or references to any results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_digital_root ?

Comment: And how does this help?

Comment: It's been proven there are infinitely many primes without $0$ in their decimal expansion, and infinitely many primes without $1$ in their decimal expansion. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01041.pdf). Maybe Maynard's argument can be adapted to prove there are infinitely many primes without $0$ *and* $1$ in their decimal expansion ? This would provide a positive answer to your question.

Comment: http://stdkmd.com/nrr/9/99997.htm If the primes of the form $10^n-3$ are infinite, then it's true. Like Mersenne primes, statistical results say they are likely to be infinite.

Comment: I am not sure, if the multiplicative digital root is computable for all naturals, then it means the process given by the OP will terminate and thus the set will always be bounded?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: Probably, even infinite many primes only consisting of the digits $8$ and $9$ exist. A proof of claims of this kind is something different. I am astonished that it can be proven that inifnite many primes without digit zero exist although this appears obvious.

Comment: @Secret I think you misinterpreted the question. The claim is that the product of the digits of a prime can become arbitary large.

Comment: @GabrielRomon The paper which you link to does in fact prove that there are infinitely many primes which do not have any of the digits $0, 1, 2$ and $3$ in their decimal expansions. It falls within the special case referred to at the end of Theorem 1.2. So the paper does provide a positive answer to the question.

Comment: @Dylan It seems to me that Maynard assumes that the basis $q$ is large enough (at multiple places in the proof he writes "$q$ large enough in terms of $\epsilon$"). I don't have time to sift carefully through the proof, can you have a look ?